# Symfony login redirects on itself

Tags: symfony

When I try and login, the page keeps redirecting on itself. This is the Firefox error I get:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

Any ideas what could be causing it?

SECURITY.YML:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FixedApp\Model\User:
          algorithm:        sha1
          encode_as_base64: false
          iterations:       1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:         [ROLE_USER, ROLE_LIMITED_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:   [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: FixedApp\Model\User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/$
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: fixed_app_authentication_login
                login_path: fixed_app_authentication_homepage
                username_parameter: username
                password_parameter: password
                default_target_path: fixed_app_authentication_homepage
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                success_handler: security.authentication.success_handler
            logout:
                path: fixed_app_authentication_logout
                target: fixed_app_homepage

    # To give access to the ROLE_LIMITED_ADMIN, use - role: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_LIMITED_ADMIN]
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/log-in$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /home, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

ROUTING.YML:

```
fixed_app_homepage:
  pattern:  /
  defaults: { _controller: FixedAppAuthenticationBundle:Default:index }

fixed_app_authentication_homepage:
  pattern:  /home
  defaults: { _controller: FixedAppAuthenticationBundle:Default:loggedIn }

fixed_app_authentication_logout:
  path: /log-out

# Verify the log in
fixed_app_authentication_login:
  pattern: /log-in
```

AUTHENTICATIONSUCCESSHANDLER.PHP
It makes no difference if I comment the return line out though.

```
function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('fixed_app_authentication_homepage'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form_login:
    login_path: fixed_app_authentication_homepage
```

Is not where you redirect to after login but in fact where you login from and it has to allow anonymous users as you get redirected there on authentication fail. So if you're seeing an authentication fail you'll get that endless redirect behaviour.

You need to allow it to be IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY

E.g.

```
- { path: /home, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

If that's not what you intended, you need to make a separate page for login_path and *then* redirect to your secure /home page on success.

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for your response. Could you explain what you mean by "If that's not what you intended, you need to make a separate page for login_path and then redirect to your secure /home page on success."?

Comment: Hi, no problem. I probably didn't word that very well. What I mean is that both check_path and login_path routes need to allow anonymous. After you successfully authenticate, *then* you can redirect in your onAuthenticationSuccess method to a secure route that requires ROLE_USER.

Comment: The problem you have currently is that if auth fails for whatever reason, Symfony will redirect you to login_path, which requires a valid user, which will redirect you again to login_path and an infinite redirect loop.